# Separator color in custom UITableView doesn't change

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have navigation controller and every VC has customTableView. In my customTableView I put UI settings inside `init()` method like this:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    separatorColor = UIColor.orange

}
```

but it doesn't work. But any other parameters of tableView like backgroundColor, sectionIndexColor and others work well. So I got problem only with separator color. Just to say, all my views and cells have clearColor.
If I put this code in view controller (that has an outlet of my customTableView) inside `viewDidLoad` method - then it works. What I'm trying to achieve is to have only one subclassed UITableView class with predefined parameters to use in every VC in my navigation stacks.

Comment: Did you try to add self? self.separatorColor = UIColor.oragne

Comment: Are you sure that you are initializing your `UITableView` with an `NSCoder`?

Comment: did you try in awake from nib or layout subviews  ?

Comment: @DJ-Glockm, yes, it doesn't help and layout subviews too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found a way to make it work. I just override `separatorColor` property in my customTableView class like this:

```
override var separatorColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return UIColor.orange
        }
        set {
            super.separatorColor = newValue
        }
    }
```

But I still cannot realise why this property cannot be set like others inside `init()` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two initializers that may be called:

**1.** `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`

this initializer will be called when view will be initialized from Interface Builder (.xib or .storyboard). To initialize view from IB set the class of some view or subview to the view class you are using.

**2.** plain `init()`

will be called when you will initialize your view from code. There may be variation of this initializer, like `init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` for UITableViewCell and so on.

So make sure if you are using right initializer. At least you can set breakpoint to see if this init is called or not.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried both, it works with ```required init()``` only since I need to implement this in all my VCs that has this subclass. As I said there is only problem with ```separatorColor```, I can even change ```separatorInset``` and it works just fine.